# How can I make gfxboot work with grub2?  

Tags: grub

There is a bunch of guides for the old `grub` but nothing for `grub2`.

I tried installing `gfxboot` and `gfxboot-themes-ubuntu` but nothing happened.

In case it is important, the `grub` is on Ubuntu Natty partition.